# mysql get capture regex?

Tags: mysql

is there a way i can write something like

```
select $1 from tbl where url regexp '/user/(\d+)'
```

getting the value as a long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` by `\\`, and the `()` is meaningless here, because you can't catch subgroup with mysql regex.

```
select SUBSTRING(url, 6) from tbl where url regexp '^/user/\\d+'
```

***Edit:***

```
select SUBSTRING(url, 6) from tbl where url regexp '^/user/[0-9]+'
```

*(mysql regex doesn't support `\d`)*

Comment: So i can match urls but I can get a part of the url?

Comment: @acidzombie24 By using string function of mysql.

Comment: \d appear to not work in mysql i am looking it up. i'll accept soon

Comment: @acidzombie24 OK, add the fixed version :)